# Validating model classes in setter methods

Tags: java, design-patterns

I would like to ask your ideas about designing best validation approach for below requirements:

We have a `User` model class and depending on it is status we can update some specific fields. As you can see, changeability of the model class depends on its status field.

- If the status of user is `ACTIVE` then all fields (name, surname,
  password ....) can be updated.
- If the status of user is `INACTIVE` only password can be updated.
- If the status of user is `BLOCKED` then name and surname can be
  updated.
- If the status of user is `DELETED` then update operation is not
  allowed for any field.

Obviously, it can be done simply by adding a `UserValidator` class and before setting values in setter methods I can call my `UserValidator` to check if the operation is allowed or not. However, it has a drawback (?): what will happen if there will be new field (let's say `maritalStatus`) and dev who adds that field forgets to call `UserValidator` before setting `maritalStatus`?

Other ways of solving this problem that I can think of:

1. Using custom annotations by extending `CustomValidator`. However, it
   won't work as annotation cannot know the previous values of object.
   I mean, the `isValid()` method of `CustomValidator` won't know if the name
   field has changed or not (it was "John" and now dev wants to change it
   to "Jack")
2. Proxy pattern could be useful but not sure if it is good idea to use
   proxy for model objects.

I've seen that the decorator pattern can be used for this problem but I don't understand how. I think validating model class is beyond the responsibility of a decorator design.

```
public class User {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String password;
    private Status status;
    // setters
}

public enum Status {
    ACTIVE, DELETED, INACTIVE, BLOCKED
}
```

Comment: what happens when a not allowed action is executed? throw an exception? keep the original value without warning?

Comment: I believe, exception should be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use intention-revealing interfaces instead of setter/getter

E.g.

```
public class User {
   private Integer id;
   private String name;
   private String surname;
   private String password;
   private Status status;


   void rename(String newName, String newSurname){
      if(Status.INACTIVE.equals(status) || Status.DELETED.equals(status))
          throws new Exception("You cannot rename a inactive or deleted user");

      this.name = newName;
      this.surname = newSurname;
   }
    .....

}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your comment! it is helpful but not really covers all the cases as the question is more like controlling editableity of fields depending on other field of same class,

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach I will use. Would be very nice if you guys can also vote for that.

Basicly I will use Decorator pattern.

```
public interface User {
    Integer getId();

    void setId(Integer id);

    String getName();

    void setName(String name);

    String getSurname();

    void setSurname(String surname);

    String getPassword();

    void setPassword(String password);

    Status getStatus();

    void setStatus(Status status);
}

public class UserImpl implements User {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String password;
    private Status status;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}


public abstract class UserDecorator  implements User{

    private final User user;

    public UserDecorator(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }


    public Integer getId() {
        return user.getId();
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        user.setId(id);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return user.getName();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        user.setName(name);
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return user.getSurname();
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        user.setSurname(surname);
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        user.setPassword(password);
    }

    public Status getStatus() {
        return user.getStatus();
    }

    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        user.setStatus(status);
    }
}
```

InActive User:

```
public class InactiveUserImpl extends UserDecorator {
    public InactiveUserImpl(User user) {
        super(user);
    }
    // didn't override setPassword therefore that field can be updated when the status of user is Inactive

    @Override
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Field can not be update when user is InActive");
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Field can not be update when user is InActive");
    }

    @Override
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Field can not be update when user is InActive");
    }

    @Override
    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Field can not be update when user is InActive");
    }
}
```

Active User:

```
public class ActiveUserImpl extends UserDecorator {
    public ActiveUserImpl(User user) {
        super(user);
    }

    // not overriding any method hence everything can be updated
}
```

Basically, whoever will ask for UserImpl I will return him wrapped version of UserImpl, For example,

```
class UserRepository{

    public User getById(String id){
        User user=db.getUserById(id);

        // this can be done with Enum but it is out of our scope

        if (user.getStatus().equals(INACTIVE))
            return new InactiveUserImpl(user);
        // ....
        return null; 
    }
}
```

If you do :

```
User user= userRepository.getById(1)
```

then you will get user with the sets of allowed setters.

Comment: I think that no decorator should allow changing the User state. Because if it is mutable you might have an ACTIVE user that has `status=INCATIVE`.

Comment: that is very valid point @elbraulio. Thank you very much for pointing this out.